# Creating area chart coloring the part of overflowed values with other color

Tags: delphi, teechart

Can you help me creating the area chart, where the part (top) of chart has other color? I would like to indicate that the values over any number value are critical.

This is a screenshot:
[image]

I've created two area charts but as you can see, each chart has own left axis. The best solution would be coloring chart above particular values.

Comment: Done that a couple of times by adding a custom chart background picture with color stripes. Works if the y-scale is fixed.

Comment: This is a screenshot:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/84/58337625.png/

I've created two area charts but as you can see, each chart has own left axis. The best solution would be coloring chart above particular values.

Answer (score 7):

There is a tool called TSeriesBandTool which can do this with a little bit of work.

Add an extra series and make it identical as your series, but with a maximum of your limit.

This is how it looks in the Tools editor :

[image]

It will fill the difference between the two series with a color of your choice.

**Update**

Made a proof of concept, see image.

Added a third Series and a second TSeriesBandTool to fill the bottom part with a second color.
I'm sure it's possible to do with less code, but this is good enough for a demonstration.

**Update 2**

Made some code refreshments.

**Update 2.5**

Now handles arbitrary X-values as well, not only integers.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
uses Series, TeeTools, TeeSeriesBandTool;

Procedure DrawLimitAreaChart(S1, S2, S3: TLineSeries; YLimit: Double;
  BT1, BT2: TSeriesBandTool; OutlineWidth: Integer;
  OutlineCL, TopCl, BottomCL: TColor);
Var
  i: Integer;
  iX: Double;
Begin
  S1.LinePen.Width := OutlineWidth;
  S1.Color := OutlineCL;
  S2.Color := OutlineCL;
  S3.Color := OutlineCL;
  for i := 0 to S1.Count - 1 do
    if (S1.YValue[i] > YLimit) then
    begin
      if (i > 0) and (S1.YValue[i - 1] < YLimit) then
      begin // Last point below limit
        iX := (S1.XValue[i] - S1.XValue[i - 1]) * (YLimit - S1.YValue[i - 1]) /
          (S1.YValue[i] - S1.YValue[i - 1]) + S1.XValue[i - 1];
        S2.AddXY(iX, YLimit);
        if (i < S1.Count - 1) then
          Continue;
      end;
      S2.AddXY(S1.XValue[i], YLimit); // Set to Ylimit
    end
    else // Below Ylimit
    begin
      if (i > 0) and (S1.YValue[i - 1] > YLimit) then
      begin // Last point above limit
        iX := (S1.XValue[i] - S1.XValue[i - 1]) * (YLimit - S1.YValue[i - 1]) /
          (S1.YValue[i] - S1.YValue[i - 1]) + S1.XValue[i - 1];
        S2.AddXY(iX, YLimit);
      end;
      S2.AddXY(S1.XValue[i], S1.YValue[i]);  // Same value
    end;

  for i := 0 to S2.Count - 1 do
  begin
    S3.AddXY(S2.XValue[i], 0.0);
  end;

  { - First TSeriesBandTool }
  BT1.Series := S1;
  BT1.Series2 := S2;
  BT1.Brush.BackColor := TopCl;
  BT1.DrawBehindSeries := True;
  BT1.Transparency := 50;

  { - Second TSeriesBandTool }
  BT2.Series := S2;
  BT2.Series2 := S3;
  BT2.Brush.BackColor := BottomCL;
  BT2.DrawBehindSeries := True;
  BT2.Transparency := 50;

End;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  // Example data
  YVAL: array [0 .. 10] of Double = (10,40,45,20,48,5,47,47,47,47,30);
var
  i: Integer;
  YLimit: Double;
  S1, S2, S3: TLineSeries;
begin
  Chart1.SeriesList.Clear;
  S1 := TLineSeries.Create(Self); // Contains real data
  Chart1.AddSeries(S1);
  S2 := TLineSeries.Create(Self); // Data below Ylimit
  Chart1.AddSeries(S2);
  S3 := TLineSeries.Create(Self); // baseline data
  Chart1.AddSeries(S3);
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    S1.AddXY(i, YVAL[i]);
  YLimit := S1.MaxYValue * 0.75;
  DrawLimitAreaChart(S1, S2, S3, YLimit, ChartTool1, ChartTool2, 2, clBlack,
    TColor($0024FF){clOrangeRed}, TColor($FF4D4D){clNeonBlue});

end;
```

So what the code does :

Fills in the X,Y data into series[0].
Calls `DrawLimitAreaChart` procedure where a new series is calculated from series[0] such that no part is above the Ylimit. Finally a third series is applied as a baseline to the second series. The three curves together with the two `TSeriesBandTools` now forms a two color region area chart.

**Update 3**

As per request here is a chart example with the X axis as time. The code for doing this is in my comment below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you master :)
How can I feed chart by data in time interval ? The procedure would be nice:

    procedure AddChartValue(ATime: TDateTime; AValue: integer);

    AddChartValue('12:00:00', 30);
    AddChartValue('12:00:10', 40);
    AddChartValue('12:00:20', 20);
    ...
    ...
    AddChartValue('12:01:50', 20);
    ....
    ....


Of course I have to set the max "x" value to show max for example 60 seconds, more data will lower clarity the chart.

Comment: I have an answer for you (please remove your other answer to the question as Ken pointed out). Set `S1.XValues.DateTime := True;` and `Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'nn:ss';` or any other format of your liking. Add X values as TDateTime format, i.e `S1.AddXY(Now + XVAL[i]/(24*60*60), YVAL[i]);`.

Comment: I hope it is working for you. Don't forget to accept the answer, see [faq#howtoask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: I tried to add an items manually

procedure TfrmQueueMonitor.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  YLimit: Double;
begin

  dbChart.Series[0].AddXY(StrToTime('12:00:10'), 50);
  dbChart.Series[0].AddXY(StrToTime('12:00:20'), 20);
  dbChart.Series[0].AddXY(StrToTime('12:00:30'), 80);

  YLimit := 30;
  DrawLimitAreaChart(dbChart.Series[0] as TLineSeries, dbChart.Series[1] as TLineSeries, dbChart.Series[2] as TLineSeries, YLimit, ChartTool1, ChartTool2, 2, clBlack,
    TColor($0024FF){clOrangeRed}, TColor($FF4D4D){clNeonBlue});
end;

but it displays 12 xvalues, why?

Comment: Are you sure the series are empty before entering Button1Click ? Otherwise call `dbChart.Series[0].Clear; dbChart.Series[1].Clear; dbChart.Series[2].Clear;` the first thing you do in Button1Click.

Comment: Yes, the series were empty. I do not have any other code except the procedure DrawLimitAreaChart and button1click. If I understood correctly the AddXY(x,y) adds x values in x-axis and y values in y axis, so when I used '12' in the x parameter the 12 items has been created. Maybe i have to use AddY(FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', now), 55) ?

Comment: Did you try my example (with the code for the time-scale X_axis included) ? I don't see that in your example above. Did you try clearing the Series ? The `Series[0].AddXY( StrToTime('12:00:00'),50);` is correct, you are entering a TDateTime value plus an Y-value of 50.